# How do turbofan engines work efficiently at cruising altitude, when the air is thinner?

Tags: jet-engine, engine, efficiency

At FL350, for example, the air is considerably thinner than at ground level. How do jet engines efficiently provide thrust when considering fuel consumption for a certain throttle setting?

Comment: By compressing the air, also note that because the air is thinner, drag on the airframe is reduced.

Comment: Isn't there less air to compress for any unit time though?

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [Why are many jet aircraft designed to cruise around FL350-370?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12541) or [Why do jet engines get better fuel efficiency at high altitudes?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/why-do-jet-engines-get-better-fuel-efficiency-at-high-altitudes) (linked to previous one).

Comment: Yes, but the engines take in a lot of air... I'm a little confused by your question though, are you under the impression that a throttle setting directly translates to a particular rated thrust output regardless of altitude?

Comment: Well throttle simply corresponds to fuel consumption. Wouldn't the same throttle setting at a lower altitude result in more thrust than the same throttle setting at a higher altitude? And if that is the case, then isn't engine efficiency compromised at such altitudes?

Comment: Yes, thrust decreases, but it isn't dumping in the same amount of fuel based on throttle settings either. There is an air/fuel ratio that needs to be maintained for optimum burn. It isn't like a mechanical linkage between the fuel valve body and the throttle handle, there is a system in there to regulate fuel (and other things).