# Why airliners fly so high even when winds are more suitable at a lower altitude?

Tags: weather, wind, flight-path, flight-level

While playing a flight sim, I noticed West winds were very strong at levels >FL350 and weaker around FL270 above the US.
I took a look at Flight Radar 24 to see at which level actual airliners were flying, and I was surprised to see they're mostly over FL350, despite the lower ground speed and increased fuel burn I assume should occur

Is there any reason for that ?

FL270 :
[image: Winds at FL270]
FL390 :
[image: Winds at FL390]

Comment: Related, if not answering the question: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12541/why-are-many-jet-aircraft-designed-to-cruise-around-fl350-370

Comment: these answers are really interesting but they don't mention winds

Comment: I think there is enough difference to not be a dupe if the focus is on why they don't fly at this height for these conditions rather than why they're generally designed to fly at a given height. The answer being that  they're designed to fly at FL350 and the detrimental effect of flying in off-design conditions is bigger than the gain from favourable winds.

Comment: @fooot that's much more like it!

Comment: indeed ! thank you @fooot !