# What is the background of the maximum altitude formula?

Tags: density-altitude

This question [What determines the maximum altitude a plane can reach?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9188/what-determines-the-maximum-altitude-a-plane-can-reach) has a formula at Peter Kämpf's answer :

$$\rho_{min} = \frac{2\cdot m\cdot g}{(Mach^2 \cdot c_L)_{max}\cdot a^2\cdot S}$$

Does anybody know what's the name of the formula or who has developed it?
Could anyone explain why $Mach^2 \cdot c_L = 0.4$ is a good value? What determines good or bad values for airfoils or what type of airfoils is requested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula can be derived equaling the weight ($W$) of an airplane with the maximum lift ($L$) generated by its wings. I'm not aware of any special name for it.

$$ W = L \\
m\cdot g= \frac{\rho_{min}}{2}\cdot V^2\cdot S\cdot c_{L,max}$$

Substituting the aircraft's speed with an expression containing the Mach number ($a$ is the local speed of sound),
$$V=Mach \cdot a$$
and solving for the density you get the formula in Peter's answer:

$$\rho_{min} = \frac{2\cdot m\cdot g}{(Mach^2 \cdot c_L)_{max}\cdot a^2\cdot S}$$

At high speeds the maximum lift coefficient is not constant. That's the reason why the Mach number and the maximum lift coefficient are written together in one term: $(Mach^2\cdot c_L)_{max}$. In order to fly as high as possible this term has to be maximized.

With [supercritical airfoils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_airfoil) you generate less drag and can therefore fly at higher Mach numbers, increasing this term.

I don't think the value 0.4 is a physical limit. Probably it is just an empirical value which takes many real-world constraints into account (if there is a physical limitation I'd be glad to read an answer explaining it). If you calculate $(Mach^2\cdot c_L)_{max}$ using [U-2's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_U-2) data you get indeed a value close to it.

Comment: I learned the formula from Mark Drela, and I also don't know a special name for it. It is easily derived, as you showed. The 0.4 is indeed empirical and what I found to be common to good designs. Maybe you get a little above that with supercritical airfoils, but not with "regular" airfoils which stay below their critical Mach number.