# What does account for a high coffin corner of a plane?

Tags: aircraft-design, transonic

The [Coffin corner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffin_corner_(aerodynamics)) is the altitude at which a plane's stall speed is close to Mach 1, the speed of sound (but still below, at the critical Mach number). What accounts for a coffin corner at *higher* altitudes? I'd think of a larger wingspan, but on the other hand larger wings would make the plane heavier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best you can do is to make the wing loading low. Wing aspect ratio helps, too, and if you look at [existing designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Condor), it will be similar to that of gliders and certainly higher than that of airliners or GA airplanes.

[This answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9188/what-determines-the-maximum-altitude-a-plane-can-reach/9227#9227) covers the characteristics which make a high altitude possible and, besides wing loading, mentions the factor $\text{Mach}^2 \cdot c_L$. Poor designs only achieve a $\text{Mach}^2 \cdot c_L$ of 0.2 whereas good ones will reach 0.4.